# How to remove non-ascii characters from a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have an object type `DataFrame` with some elements that are text and some are numbers.

when I convert a column to a list, some of the elements have non-ascii characters.
Is there a way to get rid of the characters, like `.encode('ascii', 'ignore')` but for a list?

here is the list that I get:

```
['Central Park\u202c',
 'Top of the Rock',
 'Statue of Liberty\u202c',
 'Brooklyn Bridge'
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to post-process your list, you can apply `encode('ascii', 'ignore')` over it:

```
my_list = [
    'Central Park\u202c',
    'Top of the Rock',
    'Statue of Liberty\u202c',
    'Brooklyn Bridge'
]
my_list = [e.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode("utf-8") for e in my_list]
print(my_list)
```

And the output should be:

```
['Central Park', 'Top of the Rock', 'Statue of Liberty', 'Brooklyn Bridge']
```

Comment: thanks! Do you know how i can get the same result but not encoded. i.e.,
['Central Park', 'Top of the Rock', 'Statue of Liberty', 'Brooklyn Bridge']?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `str` accessor:

```
df.my_column.str.encode('ascii','ignore').str.decode('ascii').tolist()
```